# Angular-Change Input to Uppercse

Tags: angular, input, uppercase

I have this in my input

```
oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);"
```

This works, but now i want to do this in the component

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO!, while asking a questions here do share code and some of the attempts you have done to solve our issue. And also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Method in the component

```
public changeToUpperCase(event: any) {
var start =  event.target.selectionStart;
event.target.value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
event.target.setSelectionRange(start, start);
}
```

Declaration in the <Input tag

```
(input)="changeToUpperCase($event)"
```